# Find name, category, and date of born of all sold animals?

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if what I have done makes any sense.

We have the following database

```
ANIMAL(AnimalID, Name, Category, DateBorn, ListPrice)
SALEANIMAL(SaleID, AnimalID, SalePrice)
```

I now have to find the name, category, and date of born of all sold animals

This is my idea, first I just select the columns I want in return, and from both those table, I take the rows where the SaleID is equal to AnimalID. I believe this is the way to see what animals are sold. Here is the code:

```
SELECT Name, Category, DateBorn
FROM ANIMAL A, SALEANIMAL S
WHERE S.SaleID=A.AnimalID
```

Any tips would be appreciated, I'm new to SQL

Comment: You should learn to use ANSI `JOIN` syntax instead of cross products. But the query is correct otherwise.

Comment: I think it should be A.AnimalID = S.AnimalID, as there is no saleId in Animal table.

Comment: @Pankaj oh yes, did not see that mistake, thank you